# Generic EditorTemplate for an Enum with Text Select Option Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, mvc-editor-templates

I have been using this editor template for enums:

```
@model Enum

@{
    var htmlAttributesFromView = ViewData["htmlAttributes"] ?? new { };
    var htmlAttributes = Html.MergeHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributesFromView, new { @class = "form-control" });
}



<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-8">

        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x, htmlAttributes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model)
    </div>
    <a class="infoonclick col-md-1" title="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model)" data-content="@Html.DescriptionFor(model => model)">
        <span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

The EnumDropDownListFor() gives me something like this:

```
<option value="0">blah0</option>
<option value="1">blah1</option>
```

I would like to create a version that uses the enum text (or display name) for both value and text.

```
<option value="blah0">blah0</option>
<option value="blah1">blah1</option>
```

I've found a way to do it with a template typed to a specific enum, but if possible I'd like to do it generically for all enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extension method that should help:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumTextDropDownListFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, Enum>> expression, Type enumType, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(enumType).OfType<Enum>().Select(v => v.ToString()).ToArray();
    var selectList = new SelectList(enumValues.Select(v => new SelectListItem { Text = v, Value = v }));
    return html.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob that's just the kind of thing I was looking for, appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting this error on the first line "Type provided must be an Enum. Parameter name: enumType". Any idea why? I'm googling up, but not having much luck.

Comment: Yes.  `Enum` itself doesn't count as an enum.  I take it that @model is an enum because you want maximum flexibility.  There's a way around that.  Edit pending.

Comment: Edited it.  You'll have to add `@Model.GetType()` to your call, but that should do it.