# Custom editor template for Enum - How to handle null in Create view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, mvc-editor-templates

I am trying to create a custom editor template for enum properties.

I thought I had it good. [Rob Lyndon helped me with a htmlHelper extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441236/generic-editortemplate-for-an-enum-with-text-select-option-value) and it worked great on the Edit view.

But on the Create view it errors out because the value is null.

If I make the model nullable `Enum?` then I won't be able to get the values to populate the select list.

I don't want to have to initialize all models with a default value.  And I would like to avoid having to create a different editor template for each type of enum.

Are there any better alternatives?

**HtmlHelper**

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumTextDropDownListFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, Enum>> expression, Type enumType, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(enumType).OfType<Enum>().Select(v => v.ToString()).ToArray();
    var selectList = new SelectList(enumValues.Select(v => new SelectListItem { Text = v, Value = v }));
    return html.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, htmlAttributes);
}
```

**Editor Template**

```
@model Enum

@{
    var htmlAttributesFromView = ViewData["htmlAttributes"] ?? new { };
    var htmlAttributes = Html.MergeHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributesFromView, new { @class = "form-control" });
    var type = Model.GetType();
}


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-8">

        @Html.EnumTextDropDownListFor(model => model, type, htmlAttributes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model)
    </div>
    <a class="infoonclick col-md-1" title="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model)" data-content="@Html.DescriptionFor(model => model)">
        <span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: how are you calling the template from View?

Comment: using `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyEnumProperty)` - is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
@model Enum

@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

in my `Enum.cshtml` view

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit late, but I just came across this problem and this is how I solved it:

```
@{
    var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType)
               ?? ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType;
}
```

This will allow the model to be null and avoid the nullref error you would otherwise get trying to query the type of the "null" model.

Answer (score 0):

in latest dotnet core just use the following:

1- make the model dynamic

```
@model dynamic
```

2- get the enum type with:

```
var enumType = ViewData.ModelMetadata.UnderlyingOrModelType;
```

this will handle both nullable and non-nullable enums